# Magento2.3.1: Website is not opening in chrome browser but opening in Mozilla

Tags: magento2.3.1, websites, chrome-browser

I am working on https://www.depoto.com/.

Suddenly, The website is not opening. I can see that The website is opening in another browser like Mozilla. I am trying to open in Google Chrome.

Comment: check diff browser because in mozilla browser site works perfect

Comment: @RkRathod, Yes. I just noticed that point dear. Thanks for conformation. Please tell me, How this issue will clear? I just updated my question. Check once.

Comment: It looks as if redirect is configured wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled `Strict-Transport-Security` header for your website. But still the base URL in your site is set to `http://www.depoto.com/`. Whereas Chrome is looking for HTTPS version of page with 307 redirect and yet again 302 redirect is served to http://www.depoto.com/?SID=c6d86561201c60e0a65a944bb2fd08d2 which gets into a loop. So either change the base URL to https://www.depoto.com/ or disable `Strict-Transport-Security` header which could solve your problem in Chrome

Comment: Yes, Your answer is helpful in a base url http to https case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your SSL certificate is invalid - most likely expired. Chrome is likely being more restrictive than FF. You can still visit the site by going to the http:// version but you should probably just get a proper SSL setup. Contact your hosting provider

Comment: Hello, Yes. I contacted hosting provider and cleared ssl issue too. But the issue not yet resolved